Next.js Clerk vs. NextIntl. Middleware clash
Here are three sample projects on github:

Clerk + Next-INTL. Not working
https://github.com/alexmeyercz/clerk-vs-next-intl-both
Clerk only. Works fine.
https://github.com/alexmeyercz/clerk-vs-next-intl-clerk-only
Next-INTL only. Works fine.
https://github.com/alexmeyercz/clerk-vs-next-intl-intl-only


There is just initial setup done according to documentation.
I have tried to setup middleware.ts according to documentation (Example: Integrating with Clerk
):
https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/middleware#example-integrating-with-clerk
import { authMiddleware } from '@clerk/nextjs'
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware'

const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware({
  locales: ['en', 'de'],
  defaultLocale: 'en',
})

export default authMiddleware({
  beforeAuth(request) {
    return intlMiddleware(request)
  },

  // Ensure that locale-specific sign in pages are public
  publicRoutes: ['/:locale', '/:locale/sign-in'],
})

export const config = {
  // Match only internationalized pathnames
  matcher: ['/', '/(de|en)/:path*'],
}

What is not working?
God knows what else. So far I cannot pass through the following:

Protection doesn't work (empty page, no errors: sign-in localhost link )
Clerk tags not appearing, like UserButton doesn't generate anything.
The same installation with Clerk only and Next-intl only works well
No redirects on protected pages. / is redirected to /en/, but /protected stays on /protected (not /en/protected)


You need to chain the middlewares so that they execute one after another. try the below steps:

Create a file called middlewares/middlewarechain.ts in the root directory:


import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextMiddleware } from 'next/server'

type TMiddleware = (middleware: NextMiddleware) => NextMiddleware

export function middlewarechain(
  functions: TMiddleware[],
  index = 0
): NextMiddleware {
  const current = functions[index]

  if (current) {
    const next = chain(functions, index + 1)
    return current(next)
  }

  return () => NextResponse.next()
}



Now, add this below code snippet into your middleware.ts file:


export default middlewarechain([authMiddleware, intlMiddleware])

don't forget to import the middlewarechain function into middleware.ts and you can order the functions as your needs.

Thank you very much for your answer. There are hardly any info on this topic through the internet (One documentation example and one outdated video on youtube, but none of them is helpful) I will return to this through the weekend and test it. I will provide you feedback as soon as I test it.

Thank you very much for a tip. It seems you are right and the middleware chaining is a solution, but so far, I could not make it work. The problem is me. I need to understand it better. I will update this post as soon as make sense of the whole thing.

so glad to know that bro and please let me know if you need any further assistance..

I solved the problem for sign-in form not showing by commenting out NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_URL=/sign-in
and NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_UP_URL=/sign-up  in my .env  No changes in the middleware.ts apart from those suggested by the official clerk documentation regarding integration with next-intl were necessary.

I could open a different question in SO, but I'm in the same position as OP.
There is even an entry in the documentation taking over this in https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/middleware#example-integrating-with-clerk
But with Clerk v5, it makes the /api routes not accessible anymore...

Yeah, so far I don't have it solved. I will make an attempt with the newer version of clerk soon
